# Thread is going in infinite wait state

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, wait, notify

Given an integer N, the task is to write a Java program to print the first N natural numbers in increasing order using two threads. However, the output is only showing the number 1 as the thread is going into an infinite loop and this is something the user could not debug.

```java
public class OddEven {
    static int totalNos;
    static int counter = 1;
    static Runnable odd = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                while(counter < totalNos) { 
                    while (counter%2==0) {
                        try {
                            wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print(counter + " ");
                    counter++;
                    notify();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
    static Runnable even = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                while(counter < totalNos) {
                    while (counter%2==1) {
                        try {
                            wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print(counter + " ");
                    counter++;
                    notify();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the total no's");
        Scanner scObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        totalNos = scObj.nextInt();
        scObj.close();
        Thread oddT1 = new Thread(odd);
        Thread evenT1 = new Thread(even);
        oddT1.start();
        evenT1.start();  
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as an aside, this sort of interleaving -- running one thread for a short amount of time, then waiting for another thread -- is almost always not something you'd want to do in the real world.  Threads normally should be given a substantial amount of work to properly amortize their overhead.

Comment: My first observation is that `counter` almost certainly needs to be `volatile` so each thread will see the updates.

Comment: while (counter%2==1) it appears and other code a "carbon copy" of conditions. The threads appear carbon copies so meet same requirements on wait, so both sit there on the same condition. Better define the two conditions, and walk through your work sequencing to check it's one thread after the other.

Comment: @markspace no, if there wasn’t the fundamental problem of using different objects for the synchronization, no `volatile` would be necessary.

Comment: @Holger Are you sure?  I think it's obvious that `counter` is updated by both threads (using `counter++`, no less) and must be made `volatile`.  That's not the only problem, the OP is using two locks which aren't updated by the other thread, but I'm sure `counter` is a problem as well.

Comment: @markspace when fixing the program, to use the same object for `synchronized` in both threads, the synchronization takes care of the memory visibility. With the correct synchronization, it’s impossible for the two threads to run at the same time here, as a thread can only return from `wait` when the other thread either left the `synchronized` block or entered `wait`, in other words, released the lock in some way, as returning from `wait` implies re-acquiring the lock. There is a *happens-before* relationship between releasing the lock and subsequent acquiring of the same lock.

Comment: Ah, right.  `wait()` *synchronizes-with* just like exiting a `synchronized` block.  The spec mentions `wait()` under its *happens-before* section but not in the *synchronizes-with* section (17.4.5 vs 17.4.4).  Bad spec!  @Holger

Answer (score 1):

You have no synchronization between the two objects. Each of your two objects, `even` and `odd` synchronizes on its own self, waits on its own self, and notifies its own self. Or, more accurately, it *would* notify its own self if it ever got to that point, but it doesn't get there because the other thread never notifies it.

You need to have both threads use the same object for synchronization. E.g.;

```java
public class OddEven {
    static final Object lock = new Object();
    static int totalNos;
    static int counter = 1;
    static Runnable odd = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                ...
                lock.wait();
                ...
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: I would advise to add `private` to `lock` - usually we do not want *external* code to be able to notify on it (probably valid for all fields...)

Comment: It’s weird how you use “self” to avoid “`this`”. Further, your wording is pushing beginners into the wrong direction, to think that `even` and `odd` were objects, rather than variables containing references to objects.

Comment: @Holger, That's funny, because I am usually the first one to call attention to the distinction between variables and objects and object references when failure to understand it is the root of somebody's problem; but that's not the case here. I wanted to call attention to the fact that each thread has its own distinct delegate, and it felt natural to call them out by name. I'm pretty sure that all of us are guilty of  using the names of variables to identify the objects to which they refer when there's no possibility of misunderstanding which object is meant.

Comment: @Holger, Re, "'self' to _avoid_ 'this'", I wasn't _consciously_ trying to avoid anything, though I have always felt that Java's `this` is somewhat awkward in comparison to the `self` from other languages. I'd have to spend a lot more words to express the idea contained in "its own self" if I wasn't allowed to say, "self." Also, If I'd simply said, "each object synchronizes on `this`," I wouldn't be telling the OP anything they don't already know. It's explicit in their own code.

Comment: @user16320675, I would have done without even thinking about it if OP's `counter` also had been `private`.

Comment: In case of the `wait()` and `notify()` calls, it’s not that obvious that they are invoked on `this`. But yes, the important point is not that these two threads are synchronizing on “this” but that “this” is referring to different objects. Which are the two `Runnable` instances that have been passed to the two `Thread` constructors. But maybe, your wording is easier to grasp for beginners; it would be very useful to get feedback from the OP whether it was helpful…

Comment: Updated code : static Integer counter = Integer.valueOf(1);
 static Runnable odd = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   synchronized (counter) {
    while(counter < totalNos) { 
     while (counter%2==0) {
      try {
       wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
     System.out.print(counter + " ");
     counter++;
     notify();
    }
   }
  }
 }; But Now :  Exception in thread "Thread-0" 2 Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner

Comment: That's because `wait()` is synonymous with `this.wait()`, but you need `counter.wait()`. Ditto for `notify`.